# 7zip - Create self-extracting Archive (sfx) with specified Extract path

Tags: zip, archiving, 7-zip, extract, self-extracting

I am trying to get the 7zip SFX archive to create an executable. I am able to get the executable. But when I run it, it give the downloads path for `Extract to:`. I would like to to change to `%AppData%\Roaming` by default. Screenshot below will give an idea of what I am trying to do.

[image: 7zip settings]

[image: Extract To: dialogue box]

There are no `setup.exe` or anything inside the archive, it has just few files that needs to go to `Roaming` folder. This is for many of our users, who can get this updates without them specifying a path. (It is always easy when users do not have to specify a path, otherwise, it is my experience that the users can pick most unusual paths!!)

**Update**

Here is what I have tried so far. my config file content is

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
InstallPath="%AppData%\\Roaming\\Notepad++"
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

This is the command line call.

```
copy /b 7zS.sfx + config.txt + Installer.7z myinstaller.exe
```

**Unfortunately it does not work**. It gives the following path. It should be `%AppData%\\Roaming\\Notepad++`.

[image: ![Extract path]]

Comment: This option is available with WinRAR but don't know about 7-zip.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try *[7z SFX Builder](https://sourceforge.net/projects/s-zipsfxbuilder/)*, it's free, supports command line parameters, and also you can specify extraction path on the *GUI Main Tab*:

[image: Main tab]

Comment: omegastripes, it works great. Thank you. It has amazing amount of options. Thanks a lot.

Comment: McAfee deletes the exe after installation because of a Trojan horse...

Answer (score 9):

#### I would like to change the Extract Path to `%AppData%\Roaming` by default.

You need to download a "modified module" from [7z SFX Builder](https://sourceforge.net/projects/s-zipsfxbuilder/) (sourceforge).

Check the [links on the left](https://web.archive.org/web/20160423225741/http://7zsfx.info/en/) for documentation (note these links and the text below is from https://web.archive.org/)

In your configuration file:

```
InstallPath="%AppData%\Roaming"
```

---

#### Configuration file parameters

> **InstallPath="path_to_extract"**
>
> Sets the extraction path. The extraction folder will not be deleted
>   after the extraction.
>
> If the `InstallPath` value is not present in the config file or the
>   path was deleted from the interactive extraction dialog, the archive
>   will be extracted to a temporary folder. This temporary folder will be
>   deleted after the extraction and execution of all commands.
>
> Environment variables are allowed (with the exception of `%%T` and
>   variables defined in `SetEnvironment`, if `%%T` is used in any of them).
>   You MUST use DOUBLE backslashes in paths. For example:
>
> ```
> InstallPath="C:\\Windows\\system32\\test"
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> InstallPath="%PROGRAMFILES%\\test"
> ```
>
> Relative paths are allowed. The current folder is the one from which
>   the program launching SFX archive was executed. For example,
>
> ```
> InstallPath="test"
> ```
>
> creates a folder with the name of "test" in the folder from which the
>   program launching SFX archive was executed. All files will be
>   extracted to the "test" folder. On the other hand,
>
> ```
> InstallPath="."
> ```
>
> extracts the archive content to the folder from which the program
>   launching SFX archive was executed. Also,
>
> ```
> InstallPath="%%S"
> ```
>
> extracts the archive content to the folder where the SFX is located.
>
> If all you need is to extract the archive content to a certain folder,
>   you need to specify a value for `InstallPath` in the config file.
>
> In
>   this case you should not specify `RunProgram` or `ExecuteFile` in the
>   config file. `AutoInstall` or `AutoInstallX` may be specified in the
>   config file, but should not be invoked via the command line or with
>   the [SHIFT] key.
>
> If you specify `RunProgram` or `ExecuteFile` or
>   invoke `AutoInstall` and `AutoInstallX`, the specified executable will
>   be launched after the extraction.

Source [Configuration file parameters](https://web.archive.org/web/20160423225741/http://7zsfx.info/en/)

Comment: Thanks David. But can you tell me how to use configuration file?

Comment: @Cricrazy See [General information about the modified module](http://7zsfx.info/en/) which you have to download, and check the links on the left. Answer updated.

Comment: This 7-Zip config setting `InstallPath` is just what I am looking for.  At moment I have to create a batch file to copy files from temporary extraction folder to our application's run time folder:

`;!@Install@!UTF-8!
Title="Local Manager"
InstallPath="C:\kiosk\update"
RunProgram="7zbootstrap.bat"
;!@InstallEnd@!

@ECHO OFF
REM 7zbootstrap.bat
SETLOCAL
SET update=C:\Kiosk\update
XCOPY *.* %update%\ /S /E /I /F /Y
CD %update%
ECHO LAUNCHING AUTOUPDATE.BAT SCRIPT
TIMEOUT /T 5 /NOBREAK
autoUpdate.bat`

However, [link](http://7zsfx.info/en/) no longer works.

Comment: Can't get mini-Markdown to format the code block properly.  Please amend if you know how.  Thanks.

Comment: @papertape New link is https://sourceforge.net/projects/s-zipsfxbuilder/

Comment: @papertape Answer updated with working links.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `-y -o<PathToExtract>`: `Setup.exe -y -oc:\abc`

Comment: can you give an example? what is e.g. and -oc?

Comment: "e.g" stands for "expempli gratia", which basically means "for example". It is commonly used to indicate an example, just as you request. The answer is still bare of explanation and could use formatting, but it DOES include a full example.

Comment: If you can elaborate on the command?  You should always give a break down of what commands are going to do, as the user on the other end is going to be wary of commands with functions they don't know.

Comment: Command-line parameters get passed through to the contained Exe.

Answer (score 0):

(just in case anyone is trying to do this still)

I couldn't figure out how to make a SFX archive extract to a specific location, without also specifying a setup.exe or similar file.

I managed to achieve my goal by using the `"-y -oPATH"` switches shown [here](https://superuser.com/a/1184818/105287) and storing a regular SFX archive inside a batch file ([storing a file inside a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19596027/212869))

The result is not an EXE, but a CMD file. (but *just* a CMD file)

**Method**

- create *source.exe*
- create and edit *script.cmd*
- create *combine.cmd*
- execute *combine.cmd*

*combine.cmd* as the name suggests, combines script.cmd and source.exe to create *output.cmd*

output.cmd is the result, when run, it will copy *source.exe* out of itself to a temp location, run it with the arguments specifying the location, and then delete the temp file.

**source.exe**

This is a 7z SFX Archive created using the "make sfx archive" option. It contains all the files you want to extract.

**script.cmd**

you need to replace {target} with your desired location. eg: C:\Example

you **must** add an empty new line after `exit /b` before you save this file.

```
;;;===,,,@echo off
;;;===,,,findstr /v "^;;;===,,," "%-f0" > "%temp%\tempdata.exe"
;;;===,,,start /wait "" "%temp%\tempdata.exe" -y -o"{target}"
;;;===,,,del /f /q "%temp%\tempdata.exe"
;;;===,,,exit /b
```

**combine.cmd**

```
copy /a script.cmd  /b source.exe /b output.cmd
```